# Java interact with cmd

Tags: java, windows, background, cmd, jframe

Hi and sorry for my english...

I must interact in a windows terminal with a jframe...

This is code to start the cmd

```
     try {

        String command = "file.exe";

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec(command);

        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        output = pr.getOutputStream();

        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

    } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
```

Then the jframe starts when exit from cmd line...

I need to start this in background and passing the output to the window...

How to ?

Comment: did you tried starting child process? `String command = "start cmd /c file.exe";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you should use Threads:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Then, you would be able to interact with the process instance.